# Change the default position of options in MUI

Tags: css, material-ui, makestyles

I am using [MUI](https://mui.com/) for UI.
I have some options, given in image below:

[image]
It is perfect till now. But I want to move options container to more bottom. (Currently it is set as `top: 64px` which is default).
I want to set it as `top : 100px`. After setting, it will look like :

[image]

I have tried to achieve this, but  `css`  didn't apply.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  userAge: {
    "& .Mui-focused": {
      "body .MuiPaper-root": {
        top: "100px !important" // 64px is default
      }
    }
  }
}));
//jsx return

<FormControl fullWidth className={classes.userAge}>
// more code here        
</FormControl>
```

You can also try here : https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-shannon-h6flch?file=/demo.tsx

#### Note :

I don't want to set `top : 100px` globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to your codesandbox. Hope it helps ;)

Styles need to be applied to menu via `MenuProps` and then applying class based styles to `paper`

https://codesandbox.io/s/change-the-default-position-of-options-in-mui-stackoverflow-lm9mxn?file=/demo.tsx